# DotNetNuke 7 - Synchronizing files stored in Azure Folder Provider

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke, azure-storage, dotnetnuke-7

I have DotNetNuke version 7 installed on an Azure VM. I created a folder of type Azure Folder Provider in File Manager. I would like to just upload files directly to the Azure Blob Storage container and have DotNetNuke pick up the files that are not uploaded via File Manager (which creates records of uploaded files in the dbo.Files table). Is this possible via configuration? I am looking for some guidance on this if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a documented issue with DNN 7 where the files from Azure Folder were not synchronized. Upgrading to the latest version resolves this problem.